# How can I pass my context variables to a javascript file in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, templates

This question must be obvious but I can't figure it out.

In a template, I link to a js file in my media directory. From that file, I would like to access a context variable like `{{my_chart}}`.

But is the syntax different?? Thank you!!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't think it's possible this way. If you want to access some data provided by the view, you have to pass it to the js function.

Example

js file:

```
my_cool_js_function(some_param){
    // do some cool stuff
}
```

view

```
// some html code

my_cool_js_function({{param}})
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: Remember to take a look to [{{ value|escapejs }}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs)

Answer (score 35):

In addition to Andrzej Bobak's answer, you can also generate a global variable in Javascript from your template. For example, your template might generate code like this:

```
<script>
   var my_chart = {{ the_chart }};
</script>
```

Your script could then refer to `my_chart`.

Comment: @Brian_Neal how does this work? I.e., you can just do something like `console.log(my_chart);` in the javascript file, and you don't have to declare it anywhere?

Comment: @YPCrumble It's declared in the html that is generated by Django. If that same html file also includes an external javascript file, that javascript can refer to that variable.

Comment: This is brilliant answer, as long as you declare the global variable before you import your js file, you should be fine. Thanks.

Comment: This is unsafe if {{ the_chart }} has any user entered values. What if a user decides to enter "<>/:'\;"   ?

Comment: @RyanMcGrath I haven't done Django in a long time but I believe there was/is a filter to escape javascript so maybe `{{ the_chart|escapejs }}`.

Answer (score 24):

I would also add because I ran into the error a few times that if the python variable is an object it will throw a syntax error unless you put it in quotes, in other words, within your template,

```
<script>
   var my_var = '{{ python_object|escapejs }}';
</script>
```

Furthermore, before putting that object in the context it is best to first serialize it to JSON, or you'll end up having to do string parsing. I found also that date objects needed to be converted to strings before this step.

```
import jsonpickle

context['python_object'] = jsonpickle.encode(python_object)
```

And finally, in the JS you can then iterate through the object properly and use the values as you probably would have in python by doing:

```
var my_var_parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(my_var);
```

Answer (score 14):

There is now a more secure way to pass context to a javascript file using the built-in template tag `json_script` with an argument which would be the id set for the created element.

Use case would be:

```
{{ mydata|json_script:"mydata" }}
```

Then link your javascript file:

```
<script src="{% static 'myjavascriptfile.js' %}"></script>
```

*the script tag would have to come after the template tag i'm guessing*

Which can then be accessed in your javascript file like:

```
const mydata = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('mydata').textContent);
```

### Sources

[django 3.1 docs json_script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script)

[Another source with a proper explanation](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/18/safely-including-data-for-javascript-in-a-django-template/)