# Django - passing variable to javascript file within same script tag

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to pass my variable from Django's view to a javascript file. I read the stack question here ([How can I pass my context variables to a javascript file in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683922/how-can-i-pass-my-context-variables-to-a-javascript-file-in-django)) to get a few guidance but I am trying something a little bit different. I want to pass variable to the javascript file within that particular javascript reference script tag or changing the order of variable declaration. It is easier to show by example:

My somerandom.js:

```
console.log(variable);
```

What **works**:

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
    <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
{% endblock body %}
{% block javascript %}
    <script>
      var variable = {{ my_var }};
    </script>
    <script src="{% static "app1/bootstrap/js/somerandom.js" %}"></script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

What **doesn't work**:

Edit: It doesn't work because the in developer tool (press F12 in Chrome) I see this error: *Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined*

1:

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
    <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
{% endblock body %}
{% block javascript %}
    <script src="{% static "app1/bootstrap/js/somerandom.js" %}"></script>
    <script>
      var variable = {{ my_var }};
    </script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

2:

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
    <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
{% endblock body %}
{% block javascript %}
    <script src="{% static "app1/bootstrap/js/somerandom.js" %}">
      var variable = {{ my_var }};
    </script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

Reason I want those 2 to work is so I can organize and refer to my variables properly once my code gets longer. And in this link (http://www.mutaku.com/wp/index.php/2012/03/accessing-django-template-variables-in-javascript/), it shows that we can declare variable after referencing the javascript file.

Comment: what does not work? can you give us an error string, or some stack trace? What is the "error" you see?

Comment: I added the error message I see. Basically it says "variable is not defined".

Comment: If your `somerandom.js` tries to access `variable` it is normal to get this error as you declare it later. I highly doubt the method in the page you linked to would work.

Comment: somerandom.js is accessing variable (it basically outputs variable content through console). Is there any method whereby I can declare it anywhere? I want it to be called just by somerandom.js file and not by other file.

Comment: Why don't you declare it before including your JS, as in your first (working) example?

Comment: I dont want it to be accidentally called by some other js file.

Comment: When you globally declare a JS variable as in this example it will be accessible by all functions no matter how you include it, ie. your method (2) is no different than (1).

Comment: Thanks for everybody helping. I will stick to the working method. Also according to answer by Andrea Tullimiero below, declaring in script tag for organization purpose has different behavior for each browser.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a `<script>` tag with a `src= ...` and a *content* in it the behavior is undefined, and is strongly related to the browser you're using: for instance with chrome the script is loaded from `src=...` and the content of the `<script>` is ignored 
However the usage it's strongly discouraged

Answer (score 2):

Enclosing the Django variable in double quotes worked for me. Then you invoke the .js file after the variable declaration.

```
<script>
    var variable = "{{ my_var }}";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static ... %}"></script>
```

This is because `console.log({{ my_var }})` does not print the variable to the console but `console.log("{{ my_var }}")` does print it.