# Django send data to Javascript File

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I know how to send data from Django to `html` with the view

```
def index(request):
    coord = "[[1, 2], [2, 1]"
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'coord': coord})
```

In the `html` I able to use it any where like this `{{ coord }}`, example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var geojsonObject = {
         "coordinates": {{ coord }}
     };
</script>
```

But when I try to do this in my 'index.js' I get an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

`index.html`

```
<script src="{% static 'index.js'%}"></script>
```

`index.js`

```
var geojsonObject = {
         "coordinates": {{ coord }}
};
```

I could keep everything in `index.html`, but I find it not practical to debug. How can I pass my `coor` object to the JavaScript through html?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you wanna "render" your index.js? I guess a better approach would be to modify your index.js so that if accepts the templated value as a variable. For example:

### index.html

```
<button onclick="doStuff({{ coord }})">Button</button>
```

### index.js

```js
function doStuff(coord) {
    var geojsonObject = {
         "coordinates": coord,
    };
}
```

- In this way you don't need to copy all your code to the index.html file either.
- Otherwise, you could just pass an ID to the element you are templating the value into, and then use `document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML` to access it's value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683922/how-can-i-pass-my-context-variables-to-a-javascript-file-in-django , I would encourage you to check this out as well.

Comment: I've oversimplified my view and removed everything in it. Thing is I have nothing un my `html`, the only button of my form is generated by python, the view sends the form to the `html`. I'll check if I can use the function in an other way. thx